# Memory use of giving one object to other objects

Tags: java, memory

I have a class which has BufferedImage as one of its fields. If i will use same BufferedImage object when creating n-times my class objects will it be same as making n BufferedImage objects or just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, your object has a *reference* to a BufferedImage. It doesn't have a BufferedImage in it and it doesn't matter if this reference is copied 1000x or is set to null, the object will use the same amount of space and the BufferedImage will be the same too.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be just one. Its reference will be copied into each object so the consumption will be n * the size of a reference pointer (i.e. 32 bits for a 32 bit JVM and 64 bits for a 64 bit JVM, although some implementations use 32 bits even on 64 bits JVMs).